# Get gmrun to float

Tags: xmonad

With my current config (below), `gmrun` pops up as a regular window, so it takes up the full screen if I invoke it in an empty workspace (and 1/2 the screen if there is already 1 window).  How do I modify my config so that `gmrun` pops up as a small floating window at the center of the screen?

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)


main = xmonad $ def 
    {modMask=mod4Mask, terminal="gnome-terminal"}
    `additionalKeys`
    [((mod4Mask, xK_o), spawn "gmrun")
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up [`manageHooks`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips#Managing_Windows_aka_Manage_Hooks) and use the class name "Gmrun" like so:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)

myManageHook = composeAll
   [ className =? "Gmrun" --> doFloat
   ]

main = xmonad $ def 
    {modMask=mod4Mask, terminal="gnome-terminal"
    , manageHook = myManageHook }
    `additionalKeys`
    [((mod4Mask, xK_o), spawn "gmrun")
    ]
```